# Stirling Numbers of the first kind diagonal closed form, understanding indexing.

Tags: summation, stirling-numbers

So for the signed stirling numbers of the first kind, I wanted a formula for the diagonals

[image]

On Wikipedia they describe the formula as the below. I don't quite understand how the indexing works for the sum (why is there a sum inside the index and what is the small k's)

[image]

Here the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Explicit_formula) to it. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: are you interested in **that specific** formula ? there are many other ways to compute the Stirling 1st kind

Comment: @GCab: As I read it, the question is about the notation itself.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: yes, it looks so, indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation

$$\sum_{0\le k_1,\ldots,k_p:\sum_1^pmk_m=p}f(k_1,\ldots,k_p)$$

means that we’re summing the general term $f(k_1,\ldots,k_p)$ over all $p$-tuples $\langle k_1,\ldots,k_p\rangle$ of non-negative integers such that $\sum_{m=1}^pmk_m=p$. Each of these $p$-tuples describes a partition of $p$: specifically, each $k_m$ for $m=1,\ldots,p$ is the number of parts of size $m$ in the partition. Thus, if $p=11$, the $11$-tuple $\langle 3,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\rangle$ describes the partition $11=4+2+2+1+1+1$.

The summation could also be written

$$\sum\left\{f(k_1,\ldots,k_p):0\le k_1,\ldots,k_p\text{ and }\sum_{m=1}^pmk_m=p\right\}\,.$$